# reemplazar fa icon con una imagen

Tags: javascript, html5

quiero saber si alguien puede ayudarme a reemplazar en una etiqueta `<span>`, un fa icon con una imagen, al hacer click sobre el fa icon debe abrir el cuadro de dialogo para buscar en mi equipo cualquier imagen y se coloque sobre este o lo reemplace.

```
<body>
    <div class="contentarea">
        <section class="form_wrap">
            <section class="cantact_info">
                <section class="info_title">
                    <span class="fa fa-user-circle"></span>
                    <h4>FOTO</h4>
                </section>
            </section>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tan simple Como hacer esto:

```html
<body>
    <input type="file" id="selectPicture" name="selectPicture">
    <div class="contentarea">
        <section class="form_wrap">
            <section class="cantact_info">
                <section class="info_title">
                    <label for="selectPicture"><span id="picture" class="fa fa-user-circle"></span></label>
                    <h4>FOTO</h4>
                </section>
            </section>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
```

```css
input[type=file] {
  left: -99999;
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -99999;
}
```

```
var input = document.getElementById("selectPicture");
input.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  var picture = document.getElementById("picture");
  var image = new Image(100, 100);
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    image.src = e.target.result;
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
  image.onload = function() {
    var newPicture = document.createElement('span');
    newPicture.id = "picture";
    newPicture.append(image);
    picture.parentNode.replaceChild(newPicture, picture);
  };
})
```

Comment: Excelente, funciona de maravilla. Solo hizo falta una comilla para cerrar en `input[type="file] {` pero ya quedo.

Comment: a que hace referencia el **change** en esta parte `input.addEventListener("change", function(e) {`, lo de la busqueda funciona pero al seleccionar una imagen jpg o png no veo que la reemplace, donde crees que esta el fallo?

Comment: lo he probado en chrome y firefox en mi equipo y aun así no me hace el cambio, creo que algo en mi código ha de estar afectado, te dejo un enlace solo para comprobar si se ejecuta correctamente en tu equipo de lo contrario seria el mio. https://drive.google.com/open?id=13XbC_97j8zmPjEes6g0VY-MOLeiowDz5 espero puedas indicarme si te funciona mi código.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/mivavufoqe/1/edit?html,css,js,output no encontré como cargar los fonts para que se vea a como lo tengo realmente

Comment: estas usando el mismo código que envié o modificaste algo? ya revise el ejemplo y si cambia la imagen en el tuyo

Comment: ya hice la prueba modificando todo en la pagina de jsbin y todo funciona a como debe ser, solo un detalle, cuando reemplazo el icono por una imagen lo hace en la primera pero si quiero cambiar la imagen por otra ya no la reemplaza sino se queda fija, ¿como se corrige eso?

Comment: crees que puedas revisar este código https://jsbin.com/rehawameye/edit?output es lo opuesto, busco descargar la imagen tomada, lo único que requiero es hacer funcionar el botón Save photo para guardar la imagen en mi equipo ya que en el código la guarda en una variable

Comment: @freshman podrías usar este pequeño plugin https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/blob/master/README.md